# After I change CSS not updating in the browser

Tags: css

I've tried to make the CSS changes “go live” on my site but nothing happened. Can you please help me? 
Usually when I update my CSS I need to force refresh all my browsers Chrome, Mozilla, and Opera (with F5) in order the changes in the CSS to take effect. So my problem is that I need to make the CSS to refresh automatically after a change is made.

This is the website: http://realvsbarcelona.com/
Thank you.

Comment: Do you enable any caching mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a version number in the `wp_enqueue_script()` call - fourth argument - it will append a query string to the css file reference and most (if not all) browsers will see that as a cache-breaker and force the asset to be requested again from the server.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

If you are hard-coding the script reference in your HTML then simply add a query string to the end:  `/mypath/some-stye.css?v=1234`

Any changes to that `v=1234` part will force the cached copy to be invalidated.

Comment: I've tried this, but no result:  wp_enqueue_style( 'llorix-one-lite-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('llorix-one-lite-bootstrap-style'), rand(111,9999), 'all' );

Comment: Be sure to read the documentation for the wp_enqueue_script function, which I linked within my answer.  You are passing in a random number (which is a bad idea since it will reload the css EVERY time) -- and you are passing a number not a string.  I'd try passing in a string as the $version value...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, coded into my header.php...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I think the idea is that it checks/appends the time of most recent modification, and thus serves what's current.

I'm not an expert, and will have grabbed this idea from somewhere.